# Importing a very large tab delimited file into MySQL WITHOUT first creating a table

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, csv

I have a very large tab delimited file. It's about 500 columns wide, and perhaps a million records long. It's a mix of text, dates and numbers. I'm actually only interested in a few columns from inside that - the rest will get deleted.

I want to import it into MySQL, but it's a one-off (perhaps 2- or 3-off) task and I can't really be bothered to create an empty table for a `LOAD DATA INFILE` command.

What is the lowest-effort method of achieving this? Can `LOAD DATA INFILE` be made to create a table on-the-fly with `VARCHAR`/`TEXT` columns or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a table. But if you only need certain columns, you can select them.

Create a table of the desired columns.

the you can run the `LOAD DATA` like this.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'import.csv' INTO TABLE yournewtable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
(@col1,@col2) set Colum1=@col1,Column2=@col2;
```

@col1,@col2 are variables from the CSV. Colum1,Column2 represents the columns in the table you created.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks. Just for future reference, I needed the 2nd and 229th column, I entered the following inside the brackets: `(@dummy,@col2,@dummy,@dummy,...*223,@dummy,@col229)` and then used the `@col2` and `@col229` in the final statement

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA INFILE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html allows you to specify that only certain columns will be imported.